# Is there a HTML parsing for D?

Tags: html-parsing, d

I'm looking for a HTML parsing for D language(that supports XPath, if possible). I did some googling, but no luck (hard find solutions with "D" keyword; it's like C, I say "C", google say `C#`.). On http://www.dsource.org and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-parsing+d there is no too.

Note: I want not to mix C++ and D code. I am seeking solutions either in C or in libxml2.

Comment: An XPath capable parser would have to be _very_ intelligent to be able to parse HTML. XHTML OK, but HTML is a different story... It would have to go through DOM parser...

Comment: The standard advice re search is to look for "D programming language" (and people are encouraged to include that phrase in things D related.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out Adam Ruppe's dom.d:

https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff/blob/master/dom.d

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there no documentation? how do I use it?

Comment: I saw this example to extract the favicon link: `auto document = new Document(); document.parseGarbage(html); string favicon; if(auto ele = document.querySelector("link[rel~=icon]")) { favicon = ele.href; }`

Comment: I will try it. I'm trying to compile it, but I'm getting: `module dom is in file 'arsd/dom.d' which cannot be read` how do I fix it? here's the command line that I'm using: `dmd lixo.d -I/home/foo/adamdruppe-misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff-4b5a1a9`

Comment: And the D code is `import arsd.dom; int main() { return 0; }`

Comment: You will have to rename `adamdruppe-misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff-4b5‌​a1a9` to `arsd`, because that is the name of the package adam used.

Comment: Solved! I did include of dmd [...] `dom.d characterencodings.d` files too. I thought that import only the modules was the enough. Thanks!

Comment: @CyberShadow: I did it. Thanks. Is there a `-I` equivalent to search `.d` files too? I have some d files into another directory, that I want to pass `dmd foo.d a1.d a2.d -I/baa` and do search on it. it's to replace `dmd foo.d /a/a1.d /a/a2.d` etc.

Comment: The way I use it is to just put the two modules on the command line. Then the folder name doesn't really matter.
dmd app.d dom.d characterencodings.d
will produce your binary if you put all the files together.

There is some documentation but it is super incomplete http://dpldocs.info/search/search?searchTerm=arsd.dom

Basically though, it tries to mimic the dom in web browser javascript. So you can do querySelector("css selector"), getElementById, innerHTML, innerText, etc. etc.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe:Thank you so much for your answer. I will read it now.