# How to get data from page in variable after POST request

Tags: post, d

The is page, that show data only after completing POST request from web form.

The problem that I can't understand how to get data from page in variable after sending post request.

my code:

```
void main()
{
    string baseurl = "http://www.kakioka-jma.go.jp/cgi-bin/plot/plotNN.pl";
    string postreq = "place=kak&lang=en&datatype=provisional&datakind=e&sampling=1-min&hipasssec=150&year=2015&month=2&day=18&hour=0&min=0";

    auto http = HTTP(baseurl);

    http.postData = postreq;
    auto x = http.responseHeaders();
    http.perform();
    writeln("=");
    writeln(x);
}
```

After completing `http.perform();` I see on console page content. But I do not want to output. I want to put it's in variable and then parse.

And it's looks that `writeln(x);` is empty...

Could you show example and say what I am doing wrong, please.

Comment: You need to use an HTML parser to pull out the content you want. Please see [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936434/is-there-a-html-parsing-for-d).

Comment: Before parsing data I need to get them.

Comment: Aaron's solution should work, but the reason why yours doesn't is probably because you need to setup an onReceive callback.


`string response;
http.onReceive = (ubyte[] data) {
  response ~= data;
  return data.length;
};`

Comment: Actually, that was my original answer (it's now been edited). He commented and said he wanted the data as a string, not as ubyte. I changed it to use the post() function, because his use case is simple enough that he shouldn't have to change what happens in onReceive (he just wants the text of the page).

Answer (score 1):

The std.net.curl library actually provides higher level functions for HTTP `get` and `post`. You can get the text of the page by doing this:

```
void main()
{
    string baseurl = "http://www.kakioka-jma.go.jp/cgi-bin/plot/plotNN.pl";
    string postreq = "place=kak&lang=en&datatype=provisional&datakind=e&sampling=1-min&hipasssec=150&year=2015&month=2&day=18&hour=0&min=0";
    string content = post(baseurl, postreq).idup;
    writeln(content);
}
```

Then pass `content` to your parsing function. You can also pass the variables to the perl script on this page as URL variables, with a GET call:

```
string myurl = "http://www.kakioka-jma.go.jp/cgi-bin/plot/plotNN.pl?place=kak&lang=en&datatype=provisional&datakind=e&sampling=1-min&hipasssec=150&year=2015&month=2&day=18&hour=0&min=0";
string content = get(myurl).idup;
```

Without having to worry about POSTing the data.

Comment: Could you check your example. ```Error: found 'http' when expecting ';' following statement```
Also which value would save data from page?

Also I tried to use example from link. It's print not text but digits like: ```73, 86, 62, 10, 60, 47, 66, 79, 68, 89, 62, 10, 60, 47```

Comment: Sorry, fixed the code to show how to get the HTTP response as a string. Pass that string to your parser. The `get()` and `post()` functions return a `char[]` array, but `idup` converts that into an immutable string for you.

Comment: You can also just cast a `ubyte[]` to a `char[]`.